# SQL how to set up this where clause where it checks two different fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am setting up a report in SSRS that has the Parameter OrderType

This parameters checks the box for "Allow Multiple Values"

Here is what I set up for Available Values.

```
Label        Value

Blanketed    B
Shipped      S
Open         O
```

The user can select all three or just two or one

I want to show the user the type of orders he selects. The problem is, the values for those order types are split in two fields.

Whether it is blanketed or not is under the field Order_Type, and whether it is shipped or Open is under Order_Status.

How would I set up this where clause?

This is sort of what I'm looking for in psuedocode

```
Select * from Orders O
Where (CASE WHEN @OrderType Contains 'B' THEN O.Order_Type_Code = 'B')
or (CASE WHEN @OrderType Contains 'S' THEN O.Order_Status = 45)
or (CASE WHEN @OrderType Contains 'N' THEN O.Order_Status = 10 or 20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work (I didn't test it though):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Orders o
WHERE  (@OrderType LIKE '%B%' AND o.Order_Type_Code = 'B')
   OR  (@OrderType LIKE '%S%' AND o.Order_Status = 45)
   OR  (@OrderType LIKE '%N%' AND o.Order_Status IN (10, 20));
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

```
declare @OrderType varchar(50)
set @OrderType='B'

create table #Orders(OrderNum varchar(50),Order_Type_Code varchar(50),Order_Status varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Orders VALUES('1','B','0')

declare @script nvarchar(max)
set @script='select * from #Orders where '
IF(@OrderType like '%B%')
    begin
    set @script=@script+'Order_Type_Code=''B'''
    end
IF(@OrderType like '%S%')
    begin
    set @script=@script+' or Order_Status = 45 '
    end
IF(@OrderType like '%N%')
    begin
    set @script=@script+' or Order_Type_Code in (''10'',''20'') '
    end

EXECUTE (@script)
```